# VSCode extensions greyed out but not marked deprecated

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VSCode recently updated itself (without asking me first) and messed up a lot of my extensions. Some of the extensions are marked as deprecated, as the features are now included natively in VSCode, which is fine and makes sense to me:
[image]

However, others that I relied on frequently are simply greyed out, but they are not labeled deprecated (and in many cases have relatively recent releases). Here's one example which I can no longer enable, and which is already on the latest version:
[image: Simple React Snippets]

It's not like it's super outdated either:
[image]

This is just one example of many extensions I used to rely on, and I know there are other snippet extensions out there, but when you get used to typing `sfc` and getting a whole functional component template, you prefer not to relearn a new system.

Does anybody know why these non-deprecated extensions can't be enabled anymore, or if there's a fix for this?

EDIT:
Here are a few links to examples of extensions impacted:
Name: Simple React Snippets
Id: burkeholland.simple-react-snippets
Description: Dead simple React snippets you will actually use
Version: 1.2.7
Publisher: Burke Holland
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=burkeholland.simple-react-snippets

Name: Git History
Id: donjayamanne.githistory
Description: View git log, file history, compare branches or commits
Version: 0.6.20
Publisher: Don Jayamanne
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.githistory

Name: Styled-Components Extractor
Id: FallenMax.styled-components-extractor
Description: Generate styled-components from JSX tags. A faster styled-component workflow.
Version: 0.1.1
Publisher: FallenMax
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FallenMax.styled-components-extractor

Comment: please provide a list of links to the marketplace pages of each extension where you observe this. also try restarting VS Code, and also your computer. is this a WSL, SSH or other remote VS Code connection?

Comment: @starball I added some links above. I'm not sure what you mean by your last question though. My VSCode is a local app on my Mac, the repository is local as well, and I'm working within a remote Git directory, but don't see how that applies to VSC extensions.

Comment: so you are on VS Code 1.81.1 now? does this issue reproduce after uninstalling and reinstalling VS Code? does it reproduce in [VS Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/)?

Comment: I'm on 1.79.2 it looks like. If I uninstall and reinstall, will I lose my extensions/settings?

Comment: settings or other user configuration are intentionally not removed on uninstallation of VS Code. settings and other user configuration for VS Code Insiders are kept separately from those for VS Code (they are not shared).

Comment: Are you using VS Code installed on your machine? or on the web (Ex. github.dev or vscode.dev)? Or connecting to a remote server via SSH or some other mechanism? Or VS Code Server? Do you get a message anywhere that says "_This extension is disabled by the environment_"?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem just now -

- I manually moved VScode from the finder to the applications folder
- I "Checked for updates"
- I started bisect, then restarted VScode and stopped bisect, then restarted again.
- I manually disabled and enabled all my extensions.

My extensions are working again.  I have no idea why this worked